# Why "would" instead of "will" in this sentence? Is it a rare use?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The goal for these negotiations is to reach **a mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution that *would* ensure Iran's nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful**.

What does would imply here? If it implies future, why *will* has not been used?
I have already asked this [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17074/why-would-instead-of-will-in-this-sentence) and some pals let me know this implies future happening with some uncertainty.
I need a link to an authentic reference which describes this usage of would...

Comment: I agree. The 'goal' reference takes care of the non-certainty. But they want 'a mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution that ensures (that) Iran's nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful.' 'Will ensure' could be used, to broaden the concept to 'the working out of the agreement'.

Answer (score 3):

They are correct in stating that it relates to the clause being conditional.

[Dictionaries will include this in their definitions](http://i.word.com/idictionary/would) but you may find [tutorials more useful](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/would.html), especially if you also read the articles on conditional clauses linked to from there.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the word *would* is defined in [Oxford Online English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would).

> ***would***
>
> 1. past of *will*, in
>      various senses. *he said he would be away for a couple of days she
>      wouldn’t leave the windows would not close*
> 2. **(expressing the conditional mood) indicating the consequence of an
>      imagined event or situation**: *he would lose his job if he were
>      identified*
>
>    2.1 (I would) used to give advice: *I wouldn’t drink that if I were you MORE EXAMPLE SENTENCES*
> 3. expressing a desire or inclination: *I would
>      love to work in America would you like some water?*
> 4. expressing a polite request: *would you pour the wine,
>      please?*
>
>    4.1 expressing willingness or consent: *who would live here?*
> 5. expressing a conjecture, opinion, or hope: *I would have to agree*
> 6. *chiefly • ironic* used to make a comment about behaviour that is typical: 
>      *they would say that, wouldn’t they?*
> 7. *[with clause] • literary* expressing a wish or regret: would that he had lived to finish it

What you are describing is simply the 2nd usage of *would* in the list above.

Comment: So *If they reached this a solution" it would ensure...? if so, sth has been omitted and u understood it.. Why will has not been used?